# How to copy the one input box to another on click of check box reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying copy one input box value to another input box onclick of checkbox using reactjs.

This is my Code on how to copy input value to another input.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      BillingAddress: "",
      ShippingAddress: "",
      copybilling: false
    };
  }
  changeDetails = e => {
    const { name, value, checked, maxLength } = e.target;
    const { Details, formErrors } = this.state;
    let formObj = {};
    if (name === "copybilling") {
      // handle the change event of language field
      if (checked) {
        // push selected value in list
        formObj = {
          ...Details,
          [name]: true
        };
        this.setState({
          ShippingAddress: this.state.Details.BillingAddress
        });
      } else {
        // remove unchecked value from the list
        formObj = {
          ...Details,
          [name]: false
        };
      }
    } else {
      // handle change event except language field
      formObj = {
        ...Details,
        [name]: value
      };
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <textarea
          name="BillingAddress"
          value={this.state.BillingAddress}
          onChange={this.changeDetails}
        />
        <textarea
          name="ShippingAddress"
          value={this.state.ShippingAddress}
          onChange={this.changeDetails}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On click of button, send value of input1 from its state to input2 using props

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: How are you setting the `checked` attribute of your `<textarea>` inputs?

Comment: this.setState({ buyerDetails: formObj }, () => {const errorMsg = this.validateField(
     name,
     name === "copybilling" ? this.state.Details["copybilling"] : value
    );
    formErrorsObj = { ...formErrors, [name]: errorMsg };});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      BillingAddress: "",
      ShippingAddress: "",
      copybilling: false
    };
  }

  changeDetails = e => {
    const { name, value, checked, maxLength } = e.target;
    const { Details, formErrors } = this.state;
    let formObj = {};
    if (name === "copybilling") {
      // handle the change event of language field
      if (checked) {
        // push selected value in list
        this.setState({
          [name]: true,
          ShippingAddress: this.state.BillingAddress
        });
      } else {
        // remove unchecked value from the list
        this.setState({
          [name]: false,
          ShippingAddress: ''
        });
      }
    } else {
      // handle change event except language field
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          name="BillingAddress"
          value={this.state.BillingAddress}
          onChange={this.changeDetails}
        />
        <textarea
          name="ShippingAddress"
          value={this.state.ShippingAddress}
          onChange={this.changeDetails}
        />
        Copy :
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="copybilling"
          checked={this.state.copybilling}
          onChange={this.changeDetails}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```